# Touches are in retina resolution even though app is running in non-retina mode

Tags: ios, ipad, retina-display

I have an app targeting iPad2 (non-retina 1024x768 display). I don't explicitly enable retina mode, my scale-factor is set to 1 but touch events are reporting coordinates in retina mode i.e. the *centre* of the screen is (1024,768) and the corner is (2047,1535).

I thought the whole point was iPad apps would automatically work in non-retina mode unless you explicitly enable it by changing scale-factor.

I'm using a library which does some of the UIView creation, how can I obtain the main UIView and query it to see what's happening?

For retina testing, I am relying on the simulator only - I have 6.1. However another developer confirmed it wasn't responding to touches on his iPad3 device so I'm sure it's not a simulator problem.

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be happening, can you post some related code to see if we can reproduce it? Was there a call to drawRect() or any Open GL calls? If you read the contentScaleFactor programmatically is it 1? Also, have you looked at using the convertPoint:fromView: method in UIView?

Comment: Well the library just calls a method with the coords, so it is either buggy or creates the UIView wrong. If you post code telling me how to get the primary UIView (or all UIViews so I can check them all) and inspect the relevant properties, you can have the bounty!

Comment: To do this in the past and print out the details of each view I've used this category: https://gist.github.com/nskboy/877593. That particular one adds indentation for each subview. Then you can modify  that to print out the specific properties to the debugger output. You don't need to use the category necessarily, it just helps down the road.

Answer (score 0):

I had opposite situation in my glkview app. I used screen->scale property to translate tap coords. So what you have is (as I suspect) is one of the following: (a) in your story board there is some property set for your view (inspect them all) (b) your device provides such layout (what iPad btw)?

Will later post more details.

Answer (score 0):

There are some tech mistakes, perhaps You do not read carefully Apple documentation.

1) You cannot enable/disaber retina: retina is in HW and iOS can use it correctly, You can only use it. (in some circumstances you can adapt your code to device)

2) scale factor rarely should be used (read apple doscs) and only in specialized code related to custom drawing

3) in Apple vision generally You should NOT behave different in retina HW and non-retina. 
4) Pixels and coords are LOGICAL coords, so bottom-ritght pixel is always at y= 1024 x=768.

4) You cannot have 2048 pixel resolution on a iPad2.

I don't know which library are You using, but STD behavior is different.